# Fortran passing numbers to subroutines

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

Dear Fortran Programmers,

I am quite confused with the behaviour of the following piece of simple fortran code

```
  program foo
  implicit double precision (a-h,p-w), integer*8(i-n),
 + character*12(x-z)
  xx = 'not working '
  call lskip(xx,4,8)
  call lskip2(xx,4,8)
  end

  subroutine lskip(xxx,n,m)
  implicit double precision (a-h,p-w), integer*8(i-n),
 + character*12(x-z)
  print*, ' ine lskip ',xxx,n,m
  return
  end
  subroutine lskip2(xxx,n,m)
  character*(*) xxx
  print*, ' ine lskip2 ',xxx,n,m
  return
  end
```

with `gfortran-4.2.1` the it prints something as follows.

```
ine lskip not working    7308894831428763652          17179869192
ine lskip2 not working             4           8
```

and with intel's `ifort-12.1.2` the output looks like;

```
ine lskip not working             34359738372                     8
ine lskip2 not working             4           8
```

what is wrong with `subroutine lskip()`? Why can't I use the `implicit declaration` again in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a default kind integer (usually `integer*4`) to an `integer*8`, so the representation of the integers does not match, resulting in garbage.

In the second case you are using default integers in the subroutine as well, so everything works out as expected. If you used variables in the main program to hold the values for the first and second argument, the values would be converted to the specified *kind*:

```
i1 = 4
i2 = 8
call lskip(xx,i1,i2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is not throwing a warning, but you are passing integer literals of the wrong precision here:

```
call lskip(xx,4,8)
```

Subroutine `lskip` expects the arguments to be `integer*8` while 4 and 8 have the default precision of `integer*4`.

A correct call in this case could be

```
call lskip(xx, 4_8, 8_8)
```

However, unless this is some legacy code handed to you, I **strongly suggest** avoiding writing any code in this style, which is Fortran 77 (fixed form source, no modules). Especially, since programs no longer have to fit on punch cards, **do not** use implicit typing **anywhere**, as it is the source of many evils.

A good habit is therefore to put this in the parent scope of your programs:

```
implicit none
```

Comment: Also, the compilers you mention are pretty old: gfortran is now at version 4.9, while ifort is at 14.0. gfortran gives me a type mismatch warning when compiling your source code.

Comment: `4_4` is *not necessarily* compatible to `integer*4`! You should use `integer(kind=4)` to have an equivalence!

Comment: Dear Alexander and Sigma, thanks, I thought that declaring `integer*8` will make all `integers` (variables or numbers) 8bytes by default, Thanks for your response.

Comment: Well, `integer(kind=4)` is non-portable per se, but it is 100% compatible with `4_4` whenever this kind exist, not necessarilly with `integer*4`. But I think it is important to stress implicit typing and external subroutines shouldn't be used these days as this answer does.

Comment: Dear sigma, that downvote was not intensional! I really appreciate your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the existing answers... If the program were written to use the features of Fortran 90 the compiler will automatically find the problem.  With the subroutine in a module and the module `use`d by the program, the compiler will check the arguments for consistency.   One of MANY reasons to switch from FORTRAN 77 to Fortran 90.

A quick conversion to Fortran 90:

```
module MyStuff

contains

   subroutine lskip(xxx,n,m)
      implicit double precision (a-h,p-w), integer*8(i-n), character*12(x-z)
      print*, ' ine lskip ',xxx,n,m
      return
      end
      subroutine lskip2(xxx,n,m)
      character*(*) xxx
      print*, ' ine lskip2 ',xxx,n,m
      return
   end

end module MyStuff

program foo
   use MyStuff
   implicit double precision (a-h,p-w), integer*8(i-n), character*12(x-z)
   xx = 'not working '
   call lskip(xx,4,8)
   call lskip2(xx,4,8)
end
```

This conversion doesn't eliminate implicit typing, which I fully agree should never be used.

And compiling this version, gfortran 4.9 says:

```
MyStuff.f90:22.17:

   call lskip(xx,4,8)
                 1
Error: Type mismatch in argument 'n' at (1); passed INTEGER(4) to INTEGER(8)
```

Comment: Well, everyone here suggests avoiding the `implicit typing`. If this is such an evil, why almost all fortran compilers still supporting it? Secondly, if one is working with a long piece of code, is it convenient to alway go in the start of the `processor` to declare a variable before actually using it?

Comment: Implicit typing is still supported by compilers to support "legacy" programs.  Its not worth the work and cost of recoding old programs that work.  New code should be written to higher standards, based on what has been learned about best programming practices.

Comment: @UCU110: This is because Fortran was developed in the 1950s, the era of punch card computers, where this feature saved a lot of space. Also: Fortran forces you to declare all variables in a scope before any executable statements appear, in the so called *specification part*. As an example of code accepted even by modern compilers, but terrible style, I coded [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32536) for fun yesterday. It contains nearly all of the syntax one should avoid today.